# Convergence of a sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence, $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ be partial sum.

(1) If $s_n$ is bounded, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

(2) If $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n/n=0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$, do we have the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$? If so, prove it, if not, construct a counterexample.

The first statement, I have no idea, just $a_n=a_1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{i+1}-a_i)$.

The second statement is wrong, I think; however, I could not provide a counterexample.

Comment: You can prove from $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ that $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, from there, show that its limit is zero by contradiction: if that were not the case, $s_n$ wouldn't be bounded (I think I'm assuming positive terms in my last claim).

Comment: @Devilathor How can we show that $a_n$ is Cauchy? and where $s_n$ is bounded used?

Comment: A counterexample for the second statement is the sequence $\left\{\sin\sqrt{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: This may be a necessary read https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q3h2175342p16227017

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem:**

If $\;\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is a sequence such that $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)=0\;$ and there exists $\;M\ge0\;$ such that $\;\left|\sum_\limits{i=1}^n a_i\right|\le M\;$ for all  $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;\;$ then $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;.$

**Proof:**

Let $\;s_n=\sum_\limits{i=1}^n a_i\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

So, for hypothesis, it results that $\;\left|s_n\right|\le M\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

It means that the sequence $\;\left\{s_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ of the partial sums is bounded.

Now we are going to prove this theorem through a proof by contradiction.

If the thesis were false, there would exist $\;\epsilon_0>0\;$ for which

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;\;\exists k_n\in\mathbb{N},\; k_n>n\;$ such that $\;\left|a_{k_n}\right|\ge\epsilon_0\;.$

Thus we get a sequence $\left\{k_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of positive integers such that

$k_n>n\;$ and $\;\left|a_{k_n}\right|\ge\epsilon_0\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Let $\;q=\lfloor\frac{4M}{\epsilon_0}\rfloor+1\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Since $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)=0\;$, there exists $\;\nu\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that

$\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|<\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;\;$ for all $\;n>\nu\;.\color{blue}{\quad(*)}$

Seeing as $\;k_\nu>\nu\;,\;$ from $\;(*)\;$ for $\;k_\nu\le n\le k_\nu+q-1\;$ we get that

$-\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+1}-a_{k_\nu}<\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;,$

$-\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+2}-a_{k_\nu+1}<\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;,$

$-\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+3}-a_{k_\nu+2}<\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;,$

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

$-\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+q}-a_{k_\nu+q-1}<\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;.$

By adding the first two of the previous inequalities, then the first three, the first four, etc, we also get that

$-\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+1}-a_{k_\nu}<\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;,$

$-2\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+2}-a_{k_\nu}<2\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;,$

$-3\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+3}-a_{k_\nu}<3\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;,$

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

$-q \frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}<a_{k_\nu+q}-a_{k_\nu}<q\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}\;.$

And, by adding the last inequalities, we get that

$\left|s_{k_\nu+q}-s_{k_\nu}-q a_{k_\nu}\right|<\frac{q\left(q+1\right)}{2}\frac{\epsilon_0}{q+1}=\frac{q\epsilon_0}{2}\;.$

Moreover,

$\left|s_{k_\nu+q}-s_{k_\nu}\right|\ge$

$\ge\left|q a_{k_\nu}\right|-\left|s_{k_\nu+q}-s_{k_\nu}-q a_{k_\nu}\right|>$

$>q\left|a_{k_\nu}\right|-\frac{q\epsilon_0}{2}\ge$

$\ge q\epsilon_0-\frac{q\epsilon_0}{2}=\frac{1}{2}q\epsilon_0=$

$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\lfloor\frac{4M}{\epsilon_0}\rfloor+1\right)\epsilon_0>\frac{1}{2}\frac{4M}{\epsilon_0}\epsilon_0=2M\;.$

So it results that

$\left|s_{k_\nu+q}-s_{k_\nu}\right|>2M\;.\color{blue}{\quad(**)}$

But, since $\;\left\{s_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is bounded for hypothesis, it follows that

$\left|s_{k_\nu+q}-s_{k_\nu}\right|\le\left|s_{k_\nu+q}\right|+\left|s_{k_\nu}\right|\le M+M=2M\;,$

which contradicts the inequality $\;(**)$.

So the thesis cannot be false otherwise it would lead to a contradiction.

Hence the thesis is true and it means that

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;.$

Answer (score 3):

For any $N\gt0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
s_{n+N}-s_n
&=a_{n+N}+a_{n+N-1}+\cdots+a_{n+1}\\
&=(a_{n+N}-a_{n+N-1})+2(a_{n+N-1}-a_{n+N-2})+\cdots+N(a_{n+1}-a_n)+Na_n
\end{align}$$

Now if $s_n$ is bounded, then there is some $M\gt0$ such that $|s_n|\le M$ for all $n$.  It follows that

$$|a_n|\le{2M\over N}+|a_{n+N}-a_{n+N-1}|+|a_{n+N-1}-a_{n+N-2}|+\cdots+|a_{n+1}-a_n|$$

Given $\epsilon\gt0$, choose $N$ so that $2M/N\lt\epsilon/2$ and note that, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$, there is an $m$ such that $|a_{k+1}-a_k|\lt\epsilon/(2N)$ for all $k\ge m$. With these choices of $N$ and $m$, we have

$$|a_n|\lt{\epsilon\over2}+{\epsilon\over2N}+{\epsilon\over2N}+\cdots+{\epsilon\over2N}={\epsilon\over2}+{\epsilon\over2}=\epsilon$$

for all $n\gt m$, and thus, since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

**Added later**: As for part (2), consider the following sequence for $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$:

$$0,0,{1\over2},0,{-1\over2},0,{1\over3},{2\over3},{1\over3},0,{-1\over3},{-2\over3},{-1\over3},0,0,0,0,0,0,0,{1\over4},{2\over4},{3\over4},{4\over4},{3\over4},{2\over4},{1\over4},0,{-1\over4},{-2\over4},{-3\over4},{-4\over4},{-3\over4},{-2\over4},{-1\over4},0,\ldots,0,{1\over5},\ldots{},{8\over5},\ldots,{-8\over5},\ldots,{-1\over5},0,\ldots$$

where $a_n=0$ except for a stretch after each index $n=k!$ which goes up in increments of $1/k$ to $2^{k-2}/k$, back down to $-2^{k-2}/k$, and then back up to $0$. (Note, each stretch is of length $2^k-1$, which is less than $(k+1)!-k!$, so there is always room for it, with a buffer of $0$'s between stretches.) It's clear that $a_{n-1}-a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, not hard to see that $s_n/n\to0$, and easy to see that $a_n\not\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ (indeed, the sequence $a_n$ is unbounded, since $2^{k-2}/k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the proof of (1):

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ doesn't hold, then, there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|a_n|\geq \varepsilon_0$. Here, we distinguish two cases:

CASE I: There are infinitely many negative and non-negative terms.

Then, by the condition $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$, there exists $N_0$ such that for all $n\geq N_0$: $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\varepsilon_0$, then pick some $n\geq \max\{{N_0,N}\}$ such that $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ have different sign, then $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\geq 2\varepsilon_0$ and $|a_{n+1}-a_n|< \varepsilon_0$, which is absurd.

CASE II: Case I doesn't hold.

Then, w.l.o.g., suppose that $M\in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $a_n$ is non-negative for all $n\geq M$, then, for all $n\geq \max\{{M,N}\}$: $a_n\geq \varepsilon_0$. This directly implies that $s_n$ can not be bounded.

This contradiction shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

About (2), I had the idea $a_n= 1+1/n^2$, for this sequence we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=0 \ \ ,$$
$$\frac{s_n}{n} = \frac{n+\sum^n_1 \frac{1}{k^2}}{n}$$
The last expression doesn't go to zero, but, it's a nice try, maybe you can fix it.

Comment: You were on the right track. For Case II consider $a_n = 1/n $ which is a divergent series.

Comment: @Mary No, that sequence won't work since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, which is what I'm trying to contradict.

Comment: That sequence doesn't work for that neither, the fact that the serie $\sum 1/n$ is divergent implies that $s_n$ is not bounded.

Comment: @Devilathor Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ does not hold, then what we could say is only that $\exists\ \epsilon_0>0$ such that $\forall\ N,\ \exists\ n\geq N$ such that $|a_n|\geq \epsilon_0$. thus, only a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ could verify $|a_{n_k}|\geq \epsilon_0$.

Comment: Ohh Yeah, you're right, I've negated wrong. Well, I'm sorry for the BIG mistake.

Comment: Can't we adapt the argument to that subsequence?

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem 1:**

$\left|\sum\limits_{h=1}^n\sin\sqrt{h}\right|<3\sqrt{n}+2\;\;,\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

**Proof:**

We apply the following Euler-Maclaurin summation formula

$\sum\limits_{a<h\le b} f(h)=\int_a^b\left[f(x)+\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)f’(x)\right]dx$

to the function $\;f(x)=\sin\sqrt{x}\;$.

$\sum\limits_{h=1}^n \sin\sqrt{h}=\int_0^n\left[\sin\sqrt{x}+\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right]dx\;$.

$\int_0^n\sin\sqrt{x}dx=\left[2\sin\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{x}\cos\sqrt{x}\right]_0^n=\\=2\sin\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n}\cos\sqrt{n}\;.$

$\left|\int_0^n\sin\sqrt{x}dx\right|=\left|2\sin\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n}\cos\sqrt{n}\right|\le2+2\sqrt{n}\;$.

Since $\;\left|\cos\sqrt{x}\right|\le1\;$ and $\;0\le x-\lfloor x\rfloor<1\;$, we get that

$\left|\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right|\le\frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{2\sqrt{x}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\;,$

for all $\;x\in\left]0,+\infty\right[\;$.

Hence,

$\left|\int_0^n\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx\right|\le\int_0^n\left|\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right|dx<\\<\int_0^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{n}\;.$

Therefore,

$\left|\sum\limits_{h=1}^n\sin\sqrt{h}\right|\le\left|\int_0^n\sin\sqrt{x}dx\right|+\left|\int_0^n\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}dx\right|<$

$<2+2\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}=3\sqrt{n}+2\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;$.

---

**Theorem 2:**

The sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left\{\sin\sqrt{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies the following properties:

1. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{s_n}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\sum\limits_{h=1}^n a_h}{n}=0\;;$
2. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)=0\;;$
3. $\nexists\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\;.$

**Proof:**

Since $\;\left|\cfrac{s_n}{n}\right|=\left|\cfrac{\sum\limits_{h=1}^n\sin\sqrt{h}}{n}\right|<\cfrac{3\sqrt{n}+2}{n}\;,$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$ and $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{3\sqrt{n}+2}{n}=0\;,$

it follows that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{s_n}{n}=0\;.$

Moreover,

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin\sqrt{n+1}-\sin\sqrt{n}\right)=\\=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}+2\sqrt{n}}\right)\right]=0\;,$

indeed it is a limit of a product of a bounded sequence and an infinitesimal sequence.

If there existed the limit $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\;,$ this limit would be finite, indeed the sequence $\;\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is bounded, consequently $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=l\in\mathbb{R}\;$.

And, by applying a theorem about subsequences, we get that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n=l\;,$

but it contradicts the fact that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n\;$ does not exist.

Hence the limit $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\;$ cannot exist, otherwise it would lead to a contradiction.

So we have proved by reductio ad absurdum that the limit $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\;$ does not exist.

---

**Theorem 3:**

If $\;\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is a sequence such that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{s_n}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\sum\limits_{h=1}^n a_h}{n}=0\;$ and there exists the limit $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\;,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0\;.$

**Proof:**

Since there exists $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\;,\;$ by applying a corollary of [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txta/2/txe3aa2h.htm), we get that there also exists the limit $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{s_n}{n}\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{s_n}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\;.$

But, from hypothesis, we know that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{s_n}{n}=0\;.$

Hence, by the uniqueness theorem for limits, it follows that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;.$